# How to run codedeploy agent installation script in AWS ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I have an `AWS ECS` cluster defined with a service that uses `Replica` service type. It creates an `EC2` isntance with a docker container. I can access it through browser and all this stuff...

The issue is that I have to connect through ssh to the `EC2` instance and run:

```
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install-y ruby
sudo yum install-y wget
cd /home/ec2-user
wget https://aws-codedeploy-eu-west-1.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/latest/install
chmod +x ./install
sudo ./install auto
```

It install codedeploy agent, so I can connect github to the instance and CI/CD code.
I would like to set up this automatically in every server that the `ECS` definition creates. For example if i stop the `EC2` instance, the cluster raises a new `EC2` instance, which doesn't have this agent...

I saw that I should configure your Amazon `ECS` container instance with user data, but first of all is that I am not able to find this option, and I am not quite sure if it runs into the `EC2` isntance or in the docker itself.

Comment: There are several ways of doing that. You could create Launch Template or Launch Configurations with your User Data. And use them to start your container instances.

Comment: Yes, I finally used a Launch template with user data set up :) Thank you

Comment: Cool. If you don't mind I will make an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The solution was to use [Launch Template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/LaunchTemplates.html) or [Launch Configurations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/LaunchConfiguration.html).